# how to fetch just new images on a weekly basis-PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

there is a shared drive with the server; in that shared drive there are some images which are coped by the photography department regularly. I have to write my web service and use a scheduler to call it (lets say every wednesday) and if there are **any new images** (from the last call(check)) I have to use them to show in the web site. I'm doubt about my strategy, I would like to have your confirmation to make sure I'm on the right track:

my strategy:

1)I use scandir of php to scan the drive to get all of the images in that specific folder
2)ever time that I fetch new images I put them in the database by their ID (images are saved based on IDs).
3) next week that I run my web service I check to see if the image is in Database or not. if not add it and assume it as a new image,...

Do you have any better ideas?

Comment: You could have them upload the files to a separate directory. When you check that directory for files you could move the files to the real directory. That way you know that any files in the separate directory are new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach sounds fine. However, you can do it without a database by looking at the date the file was created; just assume any file created more recently than the last time your check ran, so any file created after last Wednesday, is new.

```
$dirPath='/path/of/your/images';
$files=scandir($dirPath);
//assuming this is in fact once a week, 
//adjust '$lastCheck' based on the schedule this will run
$lastCheck=strtotime("-7 day"); 
foreach($files as $file)
{
    if (is_file("$dirPath/$file") &&  !is_link("$dirPath/$file") ) //make sure its not a directory or symlink
    {
        $createTime=filectime("$dirPath/$file");
        //check if its older than a week
        if ($createTime>$lastCheck)
        {
            //file is newer than a week
            $newFiles[]="$dirPath/$file";
        }

    }
}

//now $newFiles has all the files from this week, with no DB interaction.
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution; but I guess it does not work ; the photography department may add an image which has been created 2 weeks ago and if they simply copy this file to the shared drive it is not caught as a new file, since the creation time is 2 weeks ago although it is a new file, right?

Comment: I think you are still safe actually. The creation time of the copy will be the time the copy was created, not the original, so if the photography department copied in a 2 week old file to your directory yesterday, this script will consider it to be 1 day old.

Comment: you can verify this by doing a `stat` command in your *nix shell on a file, then copy that file, run `stat` on the new file, and compare the `Change` time, which is what registers with `filectime`

Comment: My server is a Windows Server and I tried now for a an orignial file and a copied and both returned the same number the number is :1383358968 which I dont know what exactly means!

Comment: Ah weird, I'm on Linux. I thought ctime showed creation time for windows.

Comment: ok. fyi those numbers a unix time stamp, you can see it as a date like this
`echo date("Y-m-d \ H:i:s", 1383358968);`